# Could somebody explain the following bit of code?

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I am working on a game, that involves a snake moving across the screen. 
The Following script works but i found it online, so am unsure of what exactly it does

```
var btn = new createjs.MovieClip(null, null, false, {
    up:0,over:10,down:60, out:0
}).set({
    x:250, y:570
});


createjs.Tween
    .get(o)
    .to({_off:true})
    .wait(10)
    .to({_off:false})
    .wait(10)
    .to({_off:true}),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely code exported from Adobe Animate. Animate uses CreateJS to display MovieClips with labels and timeline animations.

The first block is creating a MovieClip instance with 4 keyframes (up, over, down, out), and specifying the keyframes they are at.

Then it sets the visual x/y coordinates (likely where the clip was placed in the Animate stage).

The Tween describes a timeline where an instance is made visible/invisible every 10 "ticks/frames". The `_off` property is a special case used to toggle whether the instance is on stage or not. Note that this is applied to an instance named `o`, and not the `btn` instance in the first part of the code.

Animate exported content is not really meant to be fully understandable, since it is auto-generated based on the Animate document.